# Tangential space of subgroup of affine group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to study the Lie group of affine transformations of the form \begin{bmatrix}a&b&x\\c&d&y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}. When I parameterize it to be of the form \begin{bmatrix}a*cos(t)&-b*sin(t)&x\\a*sin(t)&b*cos(t)&y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, it defines an intrinsically 5-dimensional Lie subgroup, am I right with that? How can I determine the tangential space of the subgroup? And how do I get the adjoint representation on the Lie group and the Lie algebra?
Thank you very much and best regards

Antoni

Comment: Google for the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) $Aff(\Bbb R^n)$ and its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{aff}(\Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know the tangential space and the adjoint representation of the affine group Aff(2) without parametrization, but doesn’t the parametrization change the tangential space as well?

Comment: I think, the Euclidean isometry group would not be the one I use, because my upper left matrix is not orthogonal but in fact a subgroup of the general linear group GL(2), but with intrinsic dimension of three. Could you explain me how to get the logarithmic map of the group elements of my defined group? Is there a linear isomorphism between the Lie algebra and the Euclidean space like it is for example for the special Euclidean group SE(2)?

Comment: There I would have $[\theta x y]_G^{\wedge}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-\theta&x\\\theta&0&y\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $exp(\begin{bmatrix}0&-\theta&x\\\theta&0&y\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)&tx\\sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)&ty\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ How can I calculate it equivalently for my group?